# Secure Java Application Database

Tags: java, jdbc, embedded-database, encryption

I'm looking to build an application for managing finances.  It will be storing bank transactions, so the data file has to be secure.  I'm comfortable with SQL and JDBC, although the solution by no means has to be JDBC.  I'm looking for an embedded solution as I want the data files to be portable.

I've tried using TrueZip (http://truezip.java.net/) to create a ZIP container, then various database APIs to manage the data inside.  I've tried:

- sqlite4java (http://code.google.com/p/sqlite4java/)
- SQLiteJDBC ( http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/ )
- xBaseJ ( http://xbasej.sourceforge.net/ )

Maybe there's something simpler, an embedded DB with built in security.  (That would be the best!)  I'm not opposed to writing my own secure DB, but if there's something out there that's tested and works, I'm in!

Thanks for looking at my question.

Comment: Why wouldnt any DB like MySQL with authentication work?

Comment: Do you mean a db which can store data in encrypted files?

Comment: Maybe this answers could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451935/suggest-a-simple-nosql-database-for-java-project

Comment: Looking for a password-protected, one-file, datastore.  Something that's not just in plaintext.  H2 looks like the answer to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all all big DBMS have integrated authentication mechanisms and security.
So why not use that?
If your problem is that you want some free embedded database then check out [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html)
It is java-oriented and it offers encryption

Comment: I'm actually testing H2 right now, and it looks like exactly what I'm looking for.  Thanks for the quick response.